# Best way to detect a release build from a debug build? .net

Tags: .net, debugging, release

So I have about 10 short css files that I use with mvc app.
There are like
error.css
login.css
etc...
Just some really short css files that make updating and editing easy (At least for me). What I want is something that will optimize the if else branch and not incorporate it within the final bits. I want to do something like this

```
if(Debug.Mode){

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="error.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page.css" /> 
} else {
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css" /> 
}
```

I'll have a msbuild task that will combine all the css files, minimize them and all that good stuff. I just need to know if there is a way to remove the if else branch in the final bits.

Comment: similars questions in Stackoverflow, one question, and many, many different answers:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654450/programatically-detecting-release-debug-mode-net

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798971/how-to-idenfiy-if-the-dll-is-debug-or-release-build-in-net

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194616/how-to-tell-if-net-app-was-compiled-in-debug-or-release-mode

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50900/best-way-to-detect-a-release-build-from-a-debug-build-net

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890459/asp-net-release-build-vs-debug-build

Comment: Please refer to my posts:
[How to Tell if an Assembly is Debug or Release](http://dave-black.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-tell-if-assembly-is-debug-or.html) and
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798971/how-to-idenfiy-if-the-dll-is-debug-or-release-build-in-net/5316565#5316565](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798971/how-to-idenfiy-if-the-dll-is-debug-or-release-build-in-net/5316565#5316565)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Specifically, like this in C#:

```
#if (DEBUG)
   Debug Stuff
#endif
```

C# has the following preprocessor directives:

```
#if 
#else 
#elif // Else If
#endif
#define
#undef // Undefine
#warning // Causes the preprocessor to fire warning
#error // Causes the preprocessor to fire a fatal error
#line // Lets the preprocessor know where this source line came from
#region // Codefolding
#endregion
```

Answer (score 7):

```
  if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
  {
           // Do this
  }
  else
  {
            // Do that
  }
```

Comment: This tells you (at runtime) if a debugger is attached, but not if the assembly is a DEBUG (vs RELEASE) build.

Answer (score 6):

I should had used google.

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug mode.") 
#else 
    Console.WriteLine("Release mode.") 
#endif
```

Make sure that the option "Configuration settings" -> "Build" "Define DEBUG 
constant" in the project properties is checked.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use

```
HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
```

it is controlled by a   node in configuration. In my opinion this is nicer solution than conditional compilation.

However if you want to be able to control based on a compilation I think you can used a [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx).

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Compiler constants. I don't remember the C# syntax, but this is how I do it in VB:

```
#If CONFIG = "Debug" Then
  'do somtehing
#Else
  'do something else
#EndIf
```