# How to check if DLL is debug-compiled

Tags: .net, .net-1.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tell if .net app was compiled in DEBUG or RELEASE mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194616/how-to-tell-if-net-app-was-compiled-in-debug-or-release-mode)

Simple Question; Is there an easy way to check whether a .NET 1.1 assembly is debug-compiled or not?

Comment: Try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194616) HTH

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to check. If you want to check in code when you are actually running, if the code is in debug mode, you can use:

```
Debug.Assert(MyFunction())
```

Using that code, MyFunction will only run when the dll it is located in is compiled in debug mode.