# How can I know a dll is not a debug build

Tags: .net

How do i know for sure that my production server uses release build dll's. Is there a way to find that info inside dll?

---

Duplicate of:

- [How to tell if .net app was compiled in DEBUG or RELEASE mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194616/how-to-tell-if-net-app-was-compiled-in-debug-or-release-mode)
- [How to check if DLL is debug-compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290080/how-to-check-if-dll-is-debug-compiled)

Comment: The "Duplicate" is correct but the anwers there did not suit my needs. It a production server and i do not have access to installing neither own apps or 3rd party.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it is a c# DLL then you can use ildasm (Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\ildasm.exe) to find out this information.

1) Drag DLL into ILDASM

2) Dbl-Click on the MANIFEST

3) Look for:

//  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute/DebuggingModes) = ( 01 nn nn nn nn nn nn nn )

4) For DEBUG DLLs it will be ( 01 00 07 01 00 00 00 00 ) and for release
 (01 00 02 00 00 00 00 00) or (01 00 03 00 00 00 00)

Let me know if you need any further info!  BTW This is obviously the non programmatic solution.

Comment: Its the non-programatic solution I was looking for :)
Only problem is that ildasm.exe is not a "standard" installation for a production server.

Comment: Yep, there's nothing that'll make your system guy happier than sticking a few utilities on the Production Server! :-)  Good luck

Answer (score 2):

In your AssemlyInfo.cs you can include the following:

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Your description - Debug")]
#else
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Your description")]
#endif
```

This will make it easy to see, when using the build in properties dialog on File Explorer.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have project available for compiling again :(