# How do i come to know if dll is release or debug?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to idenfiy if the DLL is Debug or Release build (in .NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798971/how-to-idenfiy-if-the-dll-is-debug-or-release-build-in-net)
>   [How can I know a dll is not a debug build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638104/how-can-i-know-a-dll-is-not-a-debug-build)

Can some one please let me how can i find in C# .NET if the dll is build on the "Release" or "Debug" ?

Of course consider situation where is have dll/exe with me :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to idenfiy if the DLL is Debug or Release build (in .NET)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798971/how-to-idenfiy-if-the-dll-is-debug-or-release-build-in-net) and [How can I know a dll is not a debug build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638104/how-can-i-know-a-dll-is-not-a-debug-build)

Comment: Does that mean there is no quick .net command to find this ? i am little disappointed. Is my disappointment correct ?

Comment: similars questions in Stackoverflow, one question, and many, many different answers:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654450/programatically-detecting-release-debug-mode-net

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798971/how-to-idenfiy-if-the-dll-is-debug-or-release-build-in-net

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194616/how-to-tell-if-net-app-was-compiled-in-debug-or-release-mode

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50900/best-way-to-detect-a-release-build-from-a-debug-build-net

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890459/asp-net-release-build-vs-debug-build