# How to recognize dll's target platform

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfsbuild

I have .NET dll and I would like to know

1. what platform was used to build. (x86, x64 or Any CPU)
2. if it is debug or release version.

Is there a way how to find this information?

Thank you.

(I'm trying to play with TFS build server and would like to verify, that my dll are build as I want)

Comment: You can start looking at [AssemblyFlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyflagsattribute.aspx) this give you some of the info you need.

Comment: Possible repeated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-to-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64/270545#270545

Comment: Above answers the x64/x86 part. For the debug/release part, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194616/how-to-tell-if-a-net-application-was-compiled-in-debug-or-release-mode
Please search before posting!

Comment: Thanks and sorry. I had to be blind when I was searching for it..