# Programmatically detecting Release/Debug mode (.NET)

Tags: .net, debugging, release

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out if a .NET assembly was compiled with the TRACE or DEBUG flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629674)

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to idenfiy if the DLL is Debug or Release build (in .NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798971/how-to-idenfiy-if-the-dll-is-debug-or-release-build-in-net)

What's the easiest way to programmatically check if the current assembly was compiled in Debug or Release mode?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

```
bool isDebugMode = false;
#if DEBUG
isDebugMode = true;
#endif
```

If you want to program different behavior between debug and release builds you should do it like this:

```
#if DEBUG
   int[] data = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
#else
   int[] data = GetInputData();
#endif
   int sum = data[0];
   for (int i= 1; i < data.Length; i++)
   {
     sum += data[i];
   }
```

Or if you want to do certain checks on debug versions of functions you could do it like this:

```
public int Sum(int[] data)
{
   Debug.Assert(data.Length > 0);
   int sum = data[0];
   for (int i= 1; i < data.Length; i++)
   {
     sum += data[i];
   }
   return sum;
}
```

The `Debug.Assert` will not be included in the release build.

Comment: Is the OP asking about JIT Optimized build?  If so, then this answer is incorrect.  The Debug attribute can be declared in a JIT Optimized build or non-optimized.

Answer (score 15):

I hope this be useful for you:

```
public static bool IsRelease(Assembly assembly) {
    object[] attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DebuggableAttribute), true);
    if (attributes == null || attributes.Length == 0)
        return true;

    var d = (DebuggableAttribute)attributes[0];
    if ((d.DebuggingFlags & DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default) == DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.None)
        return true;

    return false;
}

public static bool IsDebug(Assembly assembly) {
    object[] attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DebuggableAttribute), true);
    if (attributes == null || attributes.Length == 0)
        return true;

    var d = (DebuggableAttribute)attributes[0];
    if (d.IsJITTrackingEnabled) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: why both function has this line:
 if (attributes == null || attributes.Length == 0)
         return true; 
Somthing is wrong with this code.
I did +1 it as the answer provides a real programmatic way rather than syntextual way to get the flag. sometime threre is a need to know if wer'e in debug mode being expressed as part of the code itself rather than a compiler flag.

Comment: The DebuggableAttribute is present if you compile in Release mode and choose DebugOutput to anything other than "none".  So, this answer is not correct.  It doesn't even look for the JIT Optimization flag.  Refer to my post on how to tell the difference both manually and programatically - http://dave-black.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-tell-if-assembly-is-debug-or.html

Comment: I defer to @DaveB on the difficulties of this in the general case.  However, your question was a broad one and, if you are simply wanting to have your code behave differently when you are testing, I find this test useful (in VB.Net) `If System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached Then  DoSomething '(Such as have a Form Behave Differently)`

Comment: Debuggers don't always have to be attached, there are plenty of scenarios where you compile in debug mode, but attach the debugger later during execution. Also most process-dump utilities (think: production support against Release builds) attach as debuggers. They aren't the same as debug-mode by any stretch, nor is this a "safe" indication a program is being tested.