# Determine if a deployed Sharepoint 2010 solution had output target set to debug

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-deployment

Is there any way to find out whether or not a sharepoint solution which was previously deployed to a 2010 sharepoint site in release mode or debug mode?

thanks,

KS

Answer (score 0):

There was a similiar question asked that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798971/how-to-idenfiy-if-the-dll-is-debug-or-release-build-in-net).  In short there is a utility called .Net Assembly Information that will give you the information you require.  The utility can be downloaded from [here](http://assemblyinformation.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the excellent tool from Nirsoft which is GacView : http://www.nirsoft.net/dot_net_tools/gac_viewer.html if the dll is now stored in the gac and you don't have any more the initial package. It will allow you to peek into the global assembly cache and gather more information with other tools if needed since you can export the dll to your disk and analyze it peacefully with other tools like the one pointed by Matt.