# C#: debug vs release.dlls

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tell if .net app was compiled in DEBUG or RELEASE mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194616/how-to-tell-if-net-app-was-compiled-in-debug-or-release-mode)

Hi,

If I have third party pre-compiled code, how can I tell if the .dll's provided are release or debug versions?

If the .pdb files exist alongside the .dll's, does that mean the dll's are debug versions?

Thanks
Nic

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194616

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798971/how-to-idenfiy-if-the-dll-is-debug-or-release-build-in-net

Comment: PDB files contain info that assists troubleshooting. Why wouldn't you want this for release builds as well?

Comment: similars questions in Stackoverflow, one question, and many, many different answers:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654450/programatically-detecting-release-debug-mode-net

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798971/how-to-idenfiy-if-the-dll-is-debug-or-release-build-in-net

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194616/how-to-tell-if-net-app-was-compiled-in-debug-or-release-mode

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50900/best-way-to-detect-a-release-build-from-a-debug-build-net

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890459/asp-net-release-build-vs-debug-build

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily - there can be .pdbs transferred as well - you could look at the dll using reflector and check that the assembly information - if there is a Assembly: debuggable information like below

[image]

then its debug

see this article fro other details http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/07/in-depth-determine-whether-a-type-method-variable-or-assembly-is-debug-or-release-build/